# Looking for birth record of Valeria Marta from late 1890s in Bucharest/Transylvania area?

Tags: birth-records, romania, 1880s, 1870s

My Grandmother Valaria Marta, was born in Bucharest or the Transylvania area in the 1870's - 1880's. Emigrated to Canada on a ship with her brother when she was 21. When they got to Canada, her brother gave her the choice of marrying one of two men he had befriended on board.

She married a Popa, also Romanian, and married Grandfather Olshanski several years later after Grandfather Popa's death. They lived in Hamilton, Ontario, Canada.

I need to find her vital records: birth certificate and/or Catholic Baptismal records so I can get a Romanian Passport and move there.

My Grandfather made hats, and she worked at his side. She took over his business after his death. She died in her 90s mid 1978, in Hamilton, Ontario, Canada.

My father, born 1921, as the youngest of 7 children. I have not been able to find any information on her, and only his death certificate. I cannot find his birth certificate either.

Comment: Welcome to G&FH SE!  As a new user please take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  From our [help/on-topic] you'll see that we cannot include precise details of persons born less than 100 years ago, without evidence of their decease being presented in the question, so your father's name has been removed.  I also removed your signature because every post you make here is already signed by your [user card](http://genealogy.stackexchange.com/users/4436/m-mckeeth).

Comment: (1) Have you reviewed the questions tagged with Romania: esp. http://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/3518/how-to-trace-ancestors-in-20th-century-romania & http://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/9172/where-to-find-birth-and-death-records-for-bucharest-romania ? (2) If your grandparents became Canadian citizens, their applications (and subsequent passports) would have to have include copies of birth records (3) Your father might have the right to dual citizenship, if his parents had not naturalized by his birth, but I don't think you would qualify.

Answer (score 1):

If you can identify the exact place of her birth would be much easy. There are registers at The Romanian National archives for that period. As soon as you identify her birth date you can ask for an official extras on her birth.